# How to use nvim command if neovim is installed using appimage?

Tags: linux, vim, neovim, coc.nvim

I have installed nvim using AppImage mentioned as below

```
curl -LO https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim.appimage
chmod u+x nvim.appimage
./nvim.appimage
```

if i use `nvim test,yml` ,it fails as '`-bash: /usr/bin/nvim: No such file or directory'`

if i use `./nvim.appimage test.yml` then it works. How to map this to nvim so that it works properly?

Comment: soft link / alias / ... ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Linux looks for binaries in the paths that are set in `$PATH` variable. To check current paths execute `echo $PATH`

One way to fix it would be to move `nvim.appimage` (and rename it to just nvim) to one of the paths set in that variable.

Another way is to append the current path of `nvim.appimage` to `$PATH`. This was answered in detail [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Answer (score 4):

Move it into /usr/local/bin/nvim

```
sudo mv nvim.appimage /usr/local/bin/nvim
```

Comment: This is already what’s the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64463403/735926) is advising.